# Struts 2 upload file destination under WebContent

Tags: java, eclipse, file-upload, struts2, nio

I would like to place Struts 2 upload files destination under `WebContent` of my application.

I already used this method:

```
ServletContext context = ServletActionContext.getServletContext();
String uploadFilePath = context.getRealPath("/uploads");
```

but `uploadFilePath` returns this

```
D:\dev\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\MyApplication\uploads
```

I would like to get this return value

```
D:\dev\workspace\MyApplication\WebContent\uploads
```

How to place Struts2 upload file destination under `WebContent`. I use Eclipse Juno and Windows7.

Comment: deploy on container & you'll get the realPath, it's the path where eclipse deployed it.

Answer (score 0):

Struts 2 places uploaded files under *temporary* folder specified for your webserver. You could copy file from this folder to you favorite destination.

```
Files.copy(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

See [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
HttpServletRequest request=(HttpServletRequest)ActionContext.getContext().get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
    String savePath =request.getRealPath("/uploads");
    //Here savePath=Application_ROOT_FOLDER\uploads
```